# Wait new terminals until die from original terminal using bash shell

Tags: bash, shell, terminal

I making CI build program. 
I using three script 
first is for build. second is for asset build. The last is for running the first and second scripts. 
I want to wait for the first and second script until they done in The last script.
Here is the test script.

The first script

```
#!/bin/sh
sleep 1
echo test2
exit 0
```

The second script

```
#!/bin/sh
sleep 1
echo test3
exit 0
```

The last script

```
#!/bin/sh
open -a /Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app ./screenTest2.sh &
open -a /Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app ./screenTest3.sh &
wait
echo test
```

how can I wait new terminals die or scripts. I'm newly in OS X. So can you explain easily that solution?

Answer (score 0):

Bash instructions are sequential just remove '&' character at the end of each line. Each instruction will execute one after the other. You can safely remove wait as well it will not be necessary to wait.

Comment: I want to build parallel so I used &

Comment: So I don't understand your problem, your script work well could you explain what do you think is wrong with your approach ?

Comment: I want to know shell script's pid on new terminals. And I found pgrep command. That can find not child of process. I use it like "pgrep - f /users/blah/command.sh". I thank you for your help